# How to convert hexadecimal representation of data to binary data in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I'm familiar with php's function `bin2hex()` for converting binary data to its hexadecimal representation.

However, what is the complement function to convert the hexadecimal representation of the data back to binary data?

For example:

```
$foo = "hello";
$foo = bin2hex($foo);
echo $foo; // Displays 68656c6c6f
```

How do I turn it back to "hello"?

```
$foo = "68656c6c6f";
// Now what?
```

There is no `hex2bin()` function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at [PHP's bin2hex page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php), there's suggested solutions including this one:

```
$foo = pack("H*" , $foo);
echo $foo;
```

There's also various implementations of hex2bin that you can choose from.

Comment: @Tony, did you pick one of the suggested solutions at random, or is this the standard one to use?

Comment: This solution seemed short, elegant, and applicable to most all versions of PHP.  I can't say if it's the canonical standard one to use, as opposed to some of the other functions provided by submitters to the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Try `pack("H*",$foo)`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 4):

For those who have PHP 5.4 and above, there's a standard way of doing this:

`<?php
    $bin = hex2bin("6578616d706c65206865782064617461");
    var_dump($bin);
?>`

The output of the code above should be similar to:

`string(16) "example hex data"`

Gotten off of the [PHP hex2bin page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php).