# How to convert string like md5 hash into a raw binary string?

Tags: php, hash, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert hexadecimal representation of data to binary data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602802/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-representation-of-data-to-binary-data-in-php)

How to convert md5 hash string based representation into its raw binary format?

Please note that `md5($data,true)` is not an option as I don't have access to `$data` but only md5 hash of it in the string format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with hex2bin http://php.net/manual/de/function.hex2bin.php (this works with PHP >= 5.4)

```
$bin = hex2bin(md5($data));
```

If you dont have PHP 5.4, try a user implementation like this http://devcorner.georgievi.net/pages/programming/php/hex2bin-php

Comment: thanks, but as noted above I don't have access to $data plus your solution can be done much simpler by just: `md5($data,true)`

Comment: Or, the alternative in the comments in the documentation...`pack("H*" , $hex_string);`

Comment: Wrikken, I have tried your solution but I am getting: `pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit` error

Comment: @Marcin: all answers here work with the hex string (Varon's also in PHP >=5.4), and well... might nog be a hex string then. Can you paste the string you're testing with here?

Comment: @Wrikken I take all back. I haven't noticed but my md5 was enclosed in double-quotes causing that error above. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept. cheers